# c# wpf mvvm light несколько Views одна ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

есть несколько views, две из которых подключены к одной viewModel. проблема в том, что создаются две сущности этой viewModel (для каждой view). как можно ограничиться одним экземпляром viewModel для нескольких view? использую mvvm light

сs:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase 
{ 
    public MenuViewModel mvm { get; private set; } 
    public MainViewModel 
    { 
        mvm = new MenuViewModel(); 
    } 
}
```

xaml:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <vm:MainViewModel x:Key="mainVM"/>
</UserControl.Resources> 
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <Binding Source="{StaticResource mainVM.mvm(здесь не получается)}">
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

Comment: mvvm light не дает явно указать вьюмодель? В чем проблема то?

Comment: я привязываю как dataContext, запускаются 2 идентичные viewModels (две сущности, для каждой view), а хотелось одну. как можно указать явно?

Comment: у меня сначала создаётся view, потом автоматически создаётся viewModel, прописанная в dataContext. не подскажите, как можно реализовать обратную схему - загружать первой viewModel? я где-то читал что это вызывает много споров, какую схему использовать. похоже нужно копать в эту сторону

Comment: Не сталкивался с mvvm light, вьюшки и вьюмодели создаю руками в нужном мне порядке. Если сейчас вьюмодель создается в разметке - переносите в код, там рулить экземплярами проще.

Comment: так?




            View v = new View();
            ViewModel vm = new ViewModel();
            v.DataContext = vm;

Comment: да, выглядит правильно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создавая главное окно, передавайте ему в конструкторе объект VM. К примеру:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow(MainViewModel mainVm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = mainVm;
    }
}
```

Теперь как это всё организовать: создавайте MainWindow в точке входа в программу(будет удобно переопределить эту точку входа). [Тут](http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/wpfintegration.html) есть подробная инструкция как это сделать, не обращайте внимания на контейнер, просто следуйте инструкции по переопределению точки входа.

Теперь в новом `Main` мы создадим окно и VM:

```
static void Main()
{
    App app = new App();
    var mainWindow = new MainWindow(new MainViewModel);
    app.Run(mainWindow);
}
```

`MainViewModel`, в свою очередь будет содержать `VM` для дочерних `View`, коих у вас два на один `VM`. Эта `VM`, для дочерних `View`, будет доступна через свойство `MainViewModel`: `MainViewModel.SubVM`, к примеру. Теперь всё, что Вам остаётся делать — это в XAML выставлять `DataContext` дочерних `View` в `MainViewModel.SubVM`

---

Зачем переопределять точку входа, почему просто не создать главный VM в том же XAML? Можно сделать и так, но вариант с переопределением — это задел на будущее.

---

Касательно Вашего кода из обновлённого вопроса, смотрите, `MainViewModel` должен быть установлен в контекст Вашего главного окна(как у меня в коде выше), затем, уже из Вашего главного окна Вы создаёте `UserControl`, назовём его `SuperControl`, и вот как мы будем создавать его в xaml главного окна:

```
<SuperControl DataContext={Binding mvm}/>
```

При условии, что `SuperControl` является потомком `MainWindow`, и `MainViewModel` выставлен в `DataContext` `MainWindow`, после выполнения строчки выше, `DataContext` оного будет выставлен в `mvm`.

Comment: спасибо за развёрнутый ответ!

Comment: только не совсем понятно что Вы имели ввиду MainViewModel, в свою очередь будет содержать VM для дочерних View

Comment: @bmo, Т.е. MainViewModel будет иметь свойства(properties) которые будут возвращать дочерние ViewModels

Comment: я так и думал :)

Comment: всё сделал, но не могу прописать DataContext как MainViewModel.SubVM :/

Comment: @bmo, а Вы добавили нужное свойство? Что не получается конкретно? Добавьте Ваш код в вопрос, чтобы было понятно

Comment: или нужно SubVM обозначить статическим полем?

Comment: готово, исправил :)

Comment: @bmo, обновил ответ

Comment: это если все находится в главном окне? у меня в главном окне вообще ничего особенного, только два ContentControl в свойства Content которых биндятся UserControls. то есть контролы - это вообще отдельные файлы.. значит остаётся только динамически назначать им DataContext, в конструкторах, как вы описали в первом ответе. полагаю что так :)

Comment: @bmo, ну `DataContext` можно пробрасывать вниз настолько, насколько это нужно. Просто Вам придётся самому подумать как лучше это сделать. Это Ваш код, я же его не знаю

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду указывать Binding к RelativeSource?

Comment: @bmo, многие свойства наследуются потомками, включая `DataContext`. Если его выставить вверху дерева, то это же значение будет доступно и внизу(если его не переназначить)

Comment: и через ContentControl тоже? если это отдельный файл?

Comment: @bmo, тут не подскажу — не знаю. Поэкспериментируйте!

Comment: сейчас буду динамически присваивать vm через конструкторы. это в следующий раз! очень интересная информация, но незаметно подкрался дэдлайн xd. ещё раз благодарю, очень помогли, плюсую Вам в карму и с наступающим праздником :)